# C# XML Deserialize Array Element Values

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've managed to deserialize my XML for the most part, but I'm stuck on one particular thing.  How do I get the value of an element, if it's in an array, and each item in that array has it's own attributes.  Let me show you what I have

```
<BusinessObject Name="BusinessName" RecID="12345">
  <FieldList>
    <Field Name="Field1">FieldValue1</Field>
    <Field Name="Field2">FieldValue2</Field>
  </FieldList>
</BusinessObject>
```

So this is a cut-down version, but shows the basis of the XML.  I'm currently having trouble trying to capture "FieldValue1" and "FieldValue2" in their respective Field elements.

```
[XmlRoot("BusinessObject")]
public sealed class BusinessObject
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("RecID")]
    public string RecID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FieldList", Type = typeof(FieldList))]
    public FieldList FieldList { get; set; }

    public BusinessObject()
    {
        FieldList = null;
    }

    public static BusinessObject FromXmlString(string xmlString)
    {
        var reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BusinessObject));
        var instance = (BusinessObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        return instance;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class FieldList
{
    [XmlElement("Field", Type = typeof(Field))]
    public Field[] Fields { get; set; }

    public FieldList()
    {
        Fields = null;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Field()
    {
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's just something simple that I'm missing, but I was having trouble trying to put my problem into words to perform a relevant search.

Many thanks,

Mark

Comment: Why wouldn't you use xsd2code : http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/? this is awesome solution for xml serialization/desirialization

Comment: Not a fix, but often a good way to debug these problems is to serialize a populated instance of your class to XML and then see what it looks like - gives you an idea of what your config actually relates to interms of the xml doc produced.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking a look.  Clearly I should play around more before posting here, as I've just managed to get it working.  I had to add the following to the Field class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Field()
    {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm just running on a copy of express here, so I couldn't work out how to use xsd without the command prompt.

Cheers all,

Mark